# Not showing all options in gpedit.msc

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, gpedit

in my system, my current login is as an administrator but even though its not allowing me to open registory editor (regedit). and to make it enabled 
i got help from this page:

http://www.bytetips.com/enable-or-disable-registry-editor/

i opened gpedit.msc but its not showing me option "system" under "User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System"

Please help me to get all rights on my system as my current user id is as administrator.
also some of my application is blocked. please tell me how to enable it. i have got 2 login, 1 as my current system's administrator and 1 as a domain user which i set as administrator for current user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find administrative template for group policy editor.
It usually has `.adm` extension

Different windows version has different option in group policy editor.

Comment: win naing: i have searched for *.adm and i found many files but done know how and in which editor i can open it .

Comment: win naing: i have opened system.adm file in wordpad and found text "POLICY !!DisableRegedit" , but dont know what to do with it.. please tell me any editor in which i can see its GUI. or suggest me changes